# Doctrine Error on Update Shopware 6.4.20.2 to 6.5.3.0

Tags: shopware6

If I run the Update Wizard I got the following Error:

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\Exception (1091)]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP FOREIGN
KEY `fk.order_customer.salutation_id`; check that it exists

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the constraint back beforehand and then try again

```sql
ALTER TABLE `order_customer` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk.order_customer.salutation_id` FOREIGN KEY (`salutation_id`) REFERENCES `salutation` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```